# Disable Logout Button at Master Page header

Tags: asp.net

How to make logout button invisible At Master Page. When in Login Page it is no sense to display logout button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use [LoginView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview(v=vs.110).aspx) for this purpose:

> Displays the appropriate content template for a given user, based on
>   the user's authentication status and role membership.

```
<asp:LoginView ID="lv" runat="server">
        <AnonymousTemplate>
            <!-- child controls -->
        </AnonymousTemplate>
        <LoggedInTemplate>
            <!-- child controls -->
        </LoggedInTemplate>       
</asp:LoginView>
```

So you can move logout button into *LoggedInTemplate* container.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `User.Identity.Name` is an empty string in master page

Answer (score 0):

Just make the button visibility false when session on userId is null on the login page.

On the page_load of LoginPage

> ```
> protected void page_load(argument e)
> {
>  if(session[userId]==null)
>    {
>    logoutbttn.visible=false;
>  }
> }
> ```